# Moving from one activity to another

Tags: android-activity

I want to move from one activity to another without using any event. My first activity displays my app logo. The name of my first activity is MainActivity and the name of my second activity is Start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - i am afraid your question is too broad and not clear - you should at least show us what you try so far.

Comment: I have edited my ques pls check

Answer (score 1):

Inside the onCreate() method of your MainActivity call this method

```
    startActivity(this, Start.class);
    finish();
```